# Trying to remove outer div results in an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The following code works:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

news_uri = 'http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011356641000/k10011356641000.html'
r = requests.get(news_uri)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
body = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'newsarticle'})

#body.div.unwrap()
for match in body.findAll('span'):
    match.unwrap()
for match in body.findAll('a'):
    match.unwrap()

print(str(body))
```

However, if you uncomment `body.div.unwrap()` it results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_div.py", line 13, in <module>
    body.div.unwrap()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unwrap'
```

I have done a test using the plain text output from:

```
body = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'newsarticle'})
```

This then works as expected and removes the outer `div`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As `body = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'newsarticle'})`, the `body` variable contains the following HTML:

```
<div id="newsarticle">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

That means, the direct descendants of the `<div>` tag are only the `<p>` tags. Using `body.div` means the code tries to find a `div` tag which is a direct descendant of the current `div` tag. Since there is no such tag present, `body.div` evaluates to `None`.

Because of this, `body.div.unwrap()` evaluates to `None.unwrap()` which as you can see will throw the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unwrap'`.

If you want to  remove the `div` tag, simply use this:

```
body = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'newsarticle'})
body.unwrap()
```

or

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'newsarticle'}).unwrap()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think your reasoning is correct but we are not quite there. When using your solution 'body' just contains the div tag:

<div id="newsarticle"></div>

but I need the content of the div tag.

Comment: First of all, why do you want to unrwap the div tag? You can simply use `.contents` to get the inner contents. If you want to get the text, you can simply use `.text`. i don't know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Also unwrap returns the deleted tag. That's the reason body contains only the div tag.

Comment: Hi, I am just trying to get the contents of the div including the other html tags.

Comment: if I take plain text with the html encompassed by the <div id="newsarticle"> then body.div.unwrap() works fine??

Comment: You don't need to use `unwrap()` to get the inner contents.